# Convenience method to initialize mutable Set in Java

Tags: java, java-collections-api

Is there a convenience method to initialize a `Set` equivalent to `Collections.singleton`, which returns a mutable `Set` instead of an immutable one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guava's [`Sets`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newHashSet%28E...%29) includes:

```
public static <E> HashSet<E> newHashSet(E... elements)
```

which:

> Creates a mutable HashSet instance containing the given elements in unspecified order.

You can call it with a single item as:

```
Sets.newHashSet(item);
```

Answer (score 12):

Guava is defintely a good solution.

Alternatively, you can do:

```
Set<T> mySet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(t1, t2, t3));
```